# position of parent class in class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

when designing a class diagram, is there any compulsion to have parent class on the top of the child class or it does not matters if the parent class is in the right left or anywhere.?

Answer (score 1):

So long as you have the right links between the different classes, you can place the parent wherever you want.

In small diagrams, traditionally one placed the parent above the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally its better to have a parent class above the child class in the UML class diagram, but sideways is okay if you've space and layout issues. If you're using a software to generate the diagrams then they figure out how to put the parent at the top pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

When I reverse the log4J java code the UML class diagram layout automatically put children under.
I suppose the layout has a logic which respect specifications.

[image]